# Return value for Node.js callback in .on() listener

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the async nature of callback. I am just looking for a pattern that present the returned value to the `console.log("1", ret);`.

Or is there an altogether better approach?

It is the callback being in an .on() that is throwing me off.

```
var _Con = require('tedious').Connection;
var _Req = require('tedious').Request;
function OnConnect_CanIConnectToTheDB(err) {
    if (err)
        return "err, could not connect to db";
    else
        return "connected to db// ";
}


function CanIConnectToTheDB() {

    var ret = "err";
    var con = new _Con({ userName: 'bla', password: 'bla', server: 'bla' })
        .on('connect', function (err) {
            ret = OnConnect_CanIConnectToTheDB(err);
            console.log(ret);
        });
    console.log("1", ret);
    return ret;
}

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(CanIConnectToTheDB());
});
```

Comment: "I get the async nature of callback" — No, you don't.

Comment: Maybe not in your great depth.

Comment: There are only two things which are true of all async functions. (1) They don't get called immediately. (2) Because of 1, you can't return their result to the function that initiated the async process. There isn't a whole lot of depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never work:

```
function CanIConnectToTheDB() {

    var ret = "err";
    var con = new _Con({ userName: 'bla', password: 'bla', server: 'bla' })
        .on('connect', function (err) {
            ret = OnConnect_CanIConnectToTheDB(err);
            console.log(ret);
        });
    console.log("1", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

That's because the `return ret;` will run before you get the value in `ret`. All you can return is a promise, like this:

```
function CanIConnectToTheDB() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var ret;
      var con = new _Con({ userName: 'bla', password: 'bla', server: 'bla' })
        .on('connect', function (err) {
            ret = OnConnect_CanIConnectToTheDB(err);
            console.log(ret);
            resolve(ret);
        });
    });
}
```

See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805) and also see:

- **[Use promises instead of callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295368/use-promises-instead-of-callbacks/42297850#42297850)**

Remember that when your function returns a promise then you have to use it like this:

```
CanIConnectToTheDB().then(result => {
  // you have result here
}).catch(error => {
  // you have error here
});
```

or:

```
CanIConnectToTheDB().then(result => {
  // you have result here
}, error => {
  // you have error here
});
```

or - only if you are inside of a function with `async` keyword:

```
try {
  let result = await CanIConnectToTheDB();
  // you have result here
} catch (error) {
  // you have error here
}
```

Note - inside of your `CanIConnectToTheDB()` you should use `resolve(value)` to resolve the promise, and `rejest(error)` to reject it.

For more info see:

- [**Answers about promises**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A613198+promise)
- [**Answers about `async`**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A613198+async)
- [**Answers about `await`**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A613198+await)

Documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: You've provided exception value.  Thank you for the well laid out and complete answer.  I knew I had to be missing something of a better approach.  I don't use node.js day int and day out.  Nor javascript.  So I wasn't thinking about promises.  But now that I see it makes total sense.

Comment: This creats a larger context issue IMO.  After connect test I want to actually query and hopfully, but never guaranteed, get one or more rows back.  Where is the most applicable place to call a method to execute the query?  In the router.get() but that doesn't have the connection. In the .on('connect')?  Then how do I return the promise, or return rows without effecting the promise?  In the OnConnect_CanIConnectToTheDB()?  What would you do to query the DB after implementing what you've shown?  A separate method creating it's own connection? The second connection isn't guaranteed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going with nesting a new 'rows' Promise inside the .on('connect') so I can append the rows result/s, or lack there of, to the return value of the returned value of the connection Promise.